# Printing Out an Enum Menu

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to print out this Enum

```
 private enum Menu
        {
            Insert("Insert"), 
            Search("Search"), 
            Size("Size"), 
            Height("Height"), 
            Clear("Clear"),
            Inorder("Inorder"),
            Preorder("Preorder");

            private String description;

            Menu()
            {
                this.description = this.name();
            }

            Menu(String name)
            {
                this.description = description;
            }

            public String toString()
            {
                return description; 
            }
         }
```

By using this:

```
            Menu[] menu = Menu.values();
            for(Menu m: menu)
            {
                System.out.printf("%d) %s%n", m.ordinal() + 1, m);
            }
```

My results are:

```
Choose an option to complete
1) null
2) null
3) null
4) null
5) null
6) null
7) null
```

How would I be able to fix this? This is my first time using enums and I'm having a tough time with trying to figure out why I'm getting this.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you are assiging the value of `description` (which is `null`) to itself...

Change

```
Menu(String name) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

To

```
Menu(String name) {
    this.description = name;
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something dumb! Thanks a lot I really appreciate it

Comment: @RandomGarbage Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following is probably what you want (and you don't need the arg-constructor) -

```
Menu(String d) {
    this.description = d;
}
```

Otherwise the `toString()` by default returns the name in the case of enums.

Answer (score 0):

plus

- remove the empty constructor, it's never called.
- don't use toString() for such a purpose because if you want to change it later it'll be hard to track where it's used. we use toString only for debug output or error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
    Menu[] menu = Menu.values();
    for(Menu m: menu)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d) %s%n", m.ordinal() + 1, m.name());
    }
```